# GridView Allowpaging Weird Behaviour

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview with

```
asp:GridView ID="gv" AllowPaging="false"
```

But when I see this is `Page_Load` then `gv.AllowPaging=true;`

Has anyone else ever seen this behaviour? I am using VS 2010 with ASP.NET 3.5 Target Framework.

Comment: Do you use skin for that GridView? If yes, check used skin definition for AllowPaging property.

Comment: No, this is a simple gridview with only asp:GridView ID="gv" AllowPaging="false". Columns are dynamically generated.

Comment: Do you use themes and skins in your project? If so, do you have default skin definition for GridView control? You may check this just setting GridView's SkinID property to some fake value like "wtfwiththisgridview"

Comment: Thanks, you are correct this was inside default skin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have default skin for all GridView controls in your project you apply any of following fixes:

1. remove `AllowPaging="true"` from the default GridView's skin definition
2. create specific skin with specified `SkinID` and apply it to the `gv` GridView
3. set fake SkinID property value on the `gv` GridView (in my opinion the most dirty solution)